# CURL/PHP - Curl BOT repeats some pages

Tags: php, curl

I've been working on a PHP/CURL script/bot that will grab stats based on user's info.
However I've had a issue where the bot will go back to /profile?id=1.
The code is the following:

```
function getData($users) {

    global $dbconfig;
    require "simple_html_dom.php";
    $noUsers = 1;
    while($users >= $noUsers) {
        $userData = array();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://domain.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . "/cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . "/cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.com/profile?id=$noUsers");
        $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
        //echo $html;

        //$fetchTwitterAuth = explode( '<tbody>' , $html );
        //$fetchTwitterAuth2 = explode('</tbody>' , $fetchTwitterAuth[1] );
        //$table = $fetchTwitterAuth2[0];
        $html=new simple_html_dom($curlResult);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
            $cell = $row->find('td', 1);
            $cell = strip_tags($cell);
            $userData[] = $cell;
            if($i == 3 && $userData[3] == "") {
                $userData[3] = "N/A";
            }
            $i = $i + 1;
        }


        $usernam = $html->find('h5');
        $userName = $usernam[0];
        $userName = strip_tags($userName);
        $SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO userdata (profileID, Name, Age, TimePlayed, Reputation, ClanName, HackCount, IPResets, DDoSServers, Spam, Warez, Missions, ProfileClick, Earned, Transfered, Hardware, Research) VALUES ('$noUsers', '$userName', '$userData[1]', '$userData[2]', '$userData[0]', '$userData[3]', '$userData[4]', '$userData[5]', '$userData[6]', '$userData[7]', '$userData[8]', '$userData[9]', '$userData[10]', '$userData[11]', '$userData[12]', '$userData[13]', '$userData[14]')";
        mysqli_query($dbconfig,$SQLQuery);
        unset($userData);
        unset($userName);
        $noUsers = $noUsers + 1;

    }
}

getData(250);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it keeps going back to random pages at random times?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laurent22.github.io/so-injections/

Comment: the code does not appear to have a way to prevent duplicate links on the page.  if it is in there, please point that out in an edit with a new block of code to show how that is happening.  in short, without that code, simply having more than one link on the page would cause it to be followed more than once.  also, it isn't clear how you are determining that it visited the page twice (for instance, you have more than one row in userdata).  finally, you could just put a unique constraint on userdata so that profileID would only go in once and the query would error or update the data instead.

Comment: @WEBjuju it's '$noUsers = $noUsers + 1;' at the bottom which defines what link to go to, once e.g ?id=1 it'll add 1 to $noUsers and the loop will repeat for the next page for $noUsers.

Comment: i see that, but if there is more than one link going to a user, there should be an array preventing duplicate traversal.  i'll give an example of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getData($users) {

    global $dbconfig;
```

Initialize an empty array to prevent duplicate links from being traversed:

```
    $users_seen = array();
```

Then do what you normally do for a few lines...

```
    require "simple_html_dom.php";
    $noUsers = 1;
    while ($users >= $noUsers) {
        $userData = array();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://domain.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . "/cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . "/cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.com/profile?id=$noUsers");
        $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
        //echo $html;

        //$fetchTwitterAuth = explode( '<tbody>' , $html );
        //$fetchTwitterAuth2 = explode('</tbody>' , $fetchTwitterAuth[1] );
        //$table = $fetchTwitterAuth2[0];
        $html=new simple_html_dom($curlResult);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
            $cell = $row->find('td', 1);
            $cell = strip_tags($cell);
            $userData[] = $cell;
            if($i == 3 && $userData[3] == "") {
                $userData[3] = "N/A";
            }
            $i = $i + 1;
        }


        $usernam = $html->find('h5');
        $userName = $usernam[0];
```

This could be an issue, too, if it can't find the userName, don't insert it.

```
        if (empty($userName)) continue;
```

If it does find a username that we haven't seen, then add it to the `$users_seen` array:

```
        if (in_array($userName, $users_seen)) {
          continue;
        } else {
          $users_seen[] = $userName;
        }
```

Now back to your regularly scheduled programming:

```
        $userName = strip_tags($userName);
        $SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO userdata (profileID, Name, Age, TimePlayed, Reputation, ClanName, HackCount, IPResets, DDoSServers, Spam, Warez, Missions, ProfileClick, Earned, Transfered, Hardware, Research) VALUES ('$noUsers', '$userName', '$userData[1]', '$userData[2]', '$userData[0]', '$userData[3]', '$userData[4]', '$userData[5]', '$userData[6]', '$userData[7]', '$userData[8]', '$userData[9]', '$userData[10]', '$userData[11]', '$userData[12]', '$userData[13]', '$userData[14]')";
        mysqli_query($dbconfig,$SQLQuery);
        unset($userData);
        unset($userName);
        $noUsers = $noUsers + 1;

    }
}

getData(250);
```

Comment: Tried your way however the usernames still is repeated

Comment: are you getting the same usernames inserted into the database?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5b926286e52869f7a8b314569f251031 - Yeah and it isn't going till the 250th user either